# WPF Binding One TextBox to two Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Perhaps a simple question, but...
So, I have bound a text box to a  property in ViewModel:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="ololo"
 Text="{Binding VM.OloloText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

And there is a TextBlock near , that could change its Text property value due to some trigger logic that I have implemented beforehand:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=typeGallery, Path=SelectedValue}"
              Value="FirstType">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="AAA" />
          </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=typeGallery, Path=SelectedValue}"
                Value="Second Type">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="BBB" />
           </DataTrigger> 
                                       ...
```

So, this TextBlock has values `AAA` or `BBB` . All this is working like a charm.
The question is how to bind the ololo TextBox to one property, say `VM.OloloText` if there is `AAA` value in TextBlock and to other property (`VM.ololoText2`)  if TextBlock value is `BBB` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a couple of `DataTrigger`s to do that for you:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ololo">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding VM.OloloText}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=YourTextBlock}"
                    Value="AAA">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding OneProperty}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=YourTextBlock}" 
                    Value="BBB">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding AnotherProperty}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Note that the `Binding` to the `VM.OloloText` property will only work if the `TextBlock` does *not* have `AAA` or `BBB` in it.

Comment: So, in fact - now it connected to two 'conditional' properties, and one default(VM.OloloText)?